# Calculating variance of estimated intercept parameter, $\hat\beta_0$

Tags: statistics, regression

I have the following sample :

$$
\begin{array}{c|lr}
X&80&100&120&140&160&180&200&220&240&260\\
\hline
Y & 70 &65&90&95&110&115&120&140&155&150 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now i have to calculate

$\mathbb V(\hat\beta_0)=\sigma^2[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar X^2}{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2}]$

here,

X is independent  and Y response variable.

$\beta_0$ intercept parameter

$\sigma^2$ population variance

But i have my sample data.

### How can i calculate $\sigma^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate the population variance $\sigma^2$, but you can estimate it with $$\widehat{\sigma^2} = \frac{\Sigma (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2}{n-2}.$$

Here, $\hat Y_i= \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$ denotes the predicted value of $Y$ given $X_i$.

Comment: Why is not the formula $\mathbb V(\hat\beta_0)=\hat\sigma^2[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar X^2}{\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2}]$ ? that is , why not it considering the estimated variance in place of population variance ?

Comment: It depends on your model assumptions: If you start with a known population variance $\sigma^2$ of your error $\varepsilon$ in $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon$, you can calculate the proper variance of the BLUE $\hat \beta$. If you don't start with a known population variance, you need to estimate it.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear